# Static property in asp.net core middleware is shared between requests?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a static class `User` with a static property `Username`. I set this property in a middleware on each url request. Then i show the `Username` to user in the header of site.

On every request, this static property is set and then shown in the view. I am assuming that each request will have it's own (correct) value in the property and the value does not get shared between different requests?

So, if request one has value `adam` and request 2 has value `john`, adam will see adam and john will see john in the header? This is working okay in my app but just want to make sure that conceptually it is right?

Comment: Static properties on objects are shared between different requests, at least as long as you're running on a single instance / single computer. However, you might look into caching for your use case instead of using static properties: [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory). You must have a key or a differntiator, otherwise all requests will see the same value.

Comment: Thanks George. I understand that static properties are shared but if a static property would have different value in each request. Is there any way that values between requests will overlap (on single computer)?

Comment: You should assume that requests run in parallel, so with static properties you can have the following situation: Req1 sets value `adam` -> Req2 sets value `john` -> Req1 prints value `john` -> Req2 prints value `john`. [Here's the official docs about sessions data and caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x). In short, values are likely to overlap (and then mostly in production, where you might have a higher load than while debugging)

Comment: No, it is not conceptually correct at all. Statics are not thread-safe. Each request is run in a separate thread and can individual modify a static affecting all other threads (and therefore requests). You should avoid statics like the plague in any multi-threaded environment, of which a web server is a primary example.

Answer (score 9):

This as you have already been informed is a good candidate for `HttpContext.Items` with a unique object key to avoid key collisions. As each context is unique for each request they will allow the values to not get shared between the different requests. You are not setting the value as a static value on the middle ware but on the current request context.

```
public class SampleMiddleware {
    public static readonly object SampleKey = new Object();

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) {
        httpContext.Items[SampleKey] = "some value";
        // additional code omitted
    }
}
```

> Other code can access the value stored in `HttpContext.Items` using
>   the key exposed by the middleware class:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public IActionResult Index() {
        string value = HttpContext.Items[SampleMiddleware.SampleKey];
    }
}
```

Reference [Introduction to session and application state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

So only the key is static but the value set in the items will be unique for each request. That means in your case that if request one has value `adam` and request 2 has value `john`, adam will see `adam` and john will see `john` in the header